# Selecting a hidden radio button in a webpage using codedUI

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to select a radio button in coded UI which is hidden. I'm doing hand coding and using Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Here is my Radio button property:

```
<span id="AddExtraDataWidget_un10_NoorgSportInd_WRAPPER">
<input id="AddExtraDataWidget_un10_No_GROUP" class="Radio" type="radio" value="AddExtraDataWidget_un10_No" onfocus="null" onblur="null" onclick="null;showHideCntrldByCaption(this.checked,'','No','false')" name="AddExtraDataWidget_un10_orgSportInd" tabindex="21"/></span>
```

I get the following exception:
"'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.**FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException**' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code"

My code is:

```
HtmlRadioButton radioButtonObject = new HtmlRadioButton(browserWindow);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Id, radioButtonObjectIDVal, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Name, radioButtonObjectNameVal, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Value, "AddExtraDataWidget_un10_No", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.ControlType, "RadioButton", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Class, "Radio", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Type, "radio", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.ClassName, "HtmlRadioButton", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
            radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.TagName, "INPUT", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

radioButtonObject.FindMatchingControls();
radioButtonObject.GetClickablePoint();
radioButtonObject.DrawHighlight();
radioButtonObject.Find();
radioButtonObject.EnsureClickable();
Mouse.Click(radioButtonObject);
radioButtonObject.Selected = fieldVal;
```

I tried almost everything suggested in these forums and MSDN too but no luck.

Can someone help me on this please? Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less is more usually when searching.  If you know the id, you only have to set the id (assuming the ids are actually unique in the page).

```
HtmlRadioButton radioButtonObject = new HtmlRadioButton(browserWindow);
radioButtonObject.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Id, "AddExtraDataWidget_un10_No_GROUP", PropertyExpressionOperator.Equals);
```

Having the extra search properties only makes the test work harder than it needs to :)

Doing a contains may be dangerous if there are more than one with this partial id.  If you need a partial match and know that more than one may be found, use FindMatchingControls() and filter down to the one you want using LINQ or something.

I have an example of finding a hidden control here http://codeduiexamples.com/examples/example1

How is your control being hidden?  Eg, display: none, visibility: hidden, removing from DOM, ...?

Comment: Based on your suggestions, i'm able to select it now. Thank you so much. Another thing i missed is not giving the correct hierarchy of the object. i.e, HtmlSpan>HtmlRadioButton  instead i was directly referencing HtmlRadioButton   Your blog is very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

For others who find this post, there's another way to solve this problem. Essentially OP had their search and filter properties incorrect. Other front-end UI frameworks (KendoUI, Angular) will create radio buttons that are "hidden" where you'll be unable to interact with them through CodedUI even if you get your properties correct. This may also affect other controls.

My solution for hand-coded tests was to write a shared method that looks something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clicks any control on a page for the given area.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="controlObject">Control Object to Click</param>
public static void ClickControl(UITestControl controlObject, int offset = 5)
{
    Rectangle clickArea = controlObject.BoundingRectangle;
    Point clickPoint = new Point(clickArea.X + offset, clickArea.Y + offset);
    Mouse.Click(clickPoint);
}
```

In plain English, this uses the bounding box for a control to click a point inside it (the X and Y values are from the top left corner). The control with a good ID may be hidden but you'll be able to click it anyway.